# Comparar Data dentro do Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando selecionar no banco a data mais proxima da data atual porem nao estou conseguindo um bom resultado.

A inserção é:

```
$titulo = trim($_POST["titulo"]);
$descricao = trim($_POST["descricao"]);
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

a consulta é:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE data > GETDATE() LIMIT 1
```

O que eu preciso é pegar a coluna DATA na tabela evento onde a DATA cadastrada seja maior que a data atual.

Comment: No banco essa consulta retornar alguma linha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Você pode desenvolver da seguinte forma:

```
$DataAtual = date("Y-m-d"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data > {$DataAtual}";
```

Desta forma busca os registros que são maiores do que a data atual.

## Ou se a $data vier do Post, faça:

```
$DataAtual = $_POST['data'];
$DataAtual = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['data'])); // caso a data venha em formato 00/00/0000 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data > {$DataAtual}";
```

> Lembre-se que o comando `data > {$DataAtual}` só serve se a data for MAIOR do que a data postada, se for igual ou maior, deve-se usar `data >= {$DataAtual}`.

Esta documentação pode te ajudar: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Para cadastrar a data eu uso o $_POST mesmo? porque se não vai cadastrar com / ou - e não mantem um padrão para comparação.

Se eu usar $data = date("d-m-Y", $_POST['data']);
Ele vai inserir: 01-09-1970
Se eu usar $data = data("DD-MM-YY", $_POST['data']);
vai inserir: TueTue-SepSep-197019701970

Comment: Sim, você pode tratar ela no retorno. Eu inseri ali o tipo de exemplo, pra que você tenha uma idéia... basta apenas decidir qual formato que vem e excluir a linha incorreta.

Comment: André, ainda não consegui.
Eu mando via post e pego com $data = date("d-m-y", $_POST['data]'); porem as datas não ficam iguais quando insiro no mysql, se eu inserir 210590 o que aparece no banco é: 03-01-70

Comment: $DataAtual = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['data'])); - Tente desta forma.

Comment: também não funciona, mesmo que eu coloque uma data futura o código cadastra a data de hoje.

Comment: Qual é o retorno?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26032/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-rafael-acioly).

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill tenho algo parecido, mas não é igual, poderia me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383064/select-case-when-datediff-retornar-expirado-ou-n%c3%a3o-com-problema-na-sa%c3%adda

Answer (score -2):

Fiz um pequeno ajuste para funcionar em meu sistema

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data > '".$DataAtual."'";

mas a lógica é a mesma