# SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF considerando horas, minutos e segundos

Tags: mysql

Criei a query para quando um plano expirasse, que a saída 'Data' imprimisse 'Expirado' e se ainda não expirou, imprimisse 'Vigente', porém preciso levar em consideração também a hora(s), minuto(s) e segundo(s) da data de expiração, pois deve bater com o mesmo tempo da data de cadastro do plano do cliente na base de dados.

O que está acontecendo é que se a data é igual a 'hoje', mas ainda não expirou completamente levando em consideração a(s) hora(s), minuto(s) e segundo(s), o retorno é 'Expirado' do mesmo jeito, e não poderia ficar assim.

O que fiz até onde consegui, se a data de expiração for maior que NOW(), está funcionando até onde eu saiba pelos testes que o fiz:

```
    $sql_plano = "SELECT 
                        *,
                        (
                        SELECT 
                            `nome` 
                        FROM 
                            `plano_pacote` 
                        WHERE 
                            `token` = `ps_token` 
                        LIMIT 
                            1
                        ) AS `plano_nome`,
                        (
                        SELECT
                            CASE
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(`data_expira`, NOW()) < 0 THEN 'Expirado' 
                            ELSE 
                                'Vigente'
                        END) AS `Data`
                    FROM 
                        `plano_usuario` 
                    WHERE 
                        `user_token` = '%s' 
                    AND 
                        `status` = 'A' 
                    ORDER BY 
                        `data_cad` 
                            DESC 
                    LIMIT 
                        1
                    ;";
```

O campo `data_expira` é do tipo `DATETIME`, e o registro está para '2019-05-10 23:51:37'

Comment: Mas DATEDIFF não é para horas e minutos. Se é para considerar tem que usar TIMEDIFF. Este tipo de coisa normalmente se resolve com uma leitura atenta ao manual.

Comment: Reverti sua edição, se quer postar a solução, use o campo de baixo, de respostas, e marque como aceito depois.

Comment: @Bacco oi, obrigado, estava editando a pergunta quando você me orientou, encontrei as referência no site do mysql  e vou estudar mais, estou começando agora a me aprofundar em sql, obrigado fera.

Comment: Ok, veja o histórico em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/383064/revisions para copiar sua solução e colar no campo apropriado (a solução vai abaixo, nas respostas, e não no corpo da pergunta)

Comment: Valeu pela dica ⁣✨

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve-se alterando DATEDIFF para TIMEDIFF [conforme as referências no site do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
    $sql_plano = "SELECT 
                    *,
                    (
                    SELECT 
                        `nome` 
                    FROM 
                        `plano_pacote` 
                    WHERE 
                        `token` = `ps_token` 
                    LIMIT 
                        1
                    ) AS `plano_nome`,
                    (
                    SELECT
                        CASE
                            WHEN DATEDIFF(`data_expira`, NOW()) < 0 THEN 'Expirado' 
                        ELSE 
                            'Vigente'
                    END) AS `Data`
                FROM 
                    `plano_usuario` 
                WHERE 
                    `user_token` = '%s' 
                AND 
                    `status` = 'A' 
                ORDER BY 
                    `data_cad` 
                        DESC 
                LIMIT 
                    1
                ;";
```

Alterado para:

```
    $sql_plano = "SELECT 
                    *,
                    (
                    SELECT 
                        `nome` 
                    FROM 
                        `plano_pacote` 
                    WHERE 
                        `token` = `ps_token` 
                    LIMIT 
                        1
                    ) AS `plano_nome`,
                    (
                    SELECT
                        CASE
                            WHEN TIMEDIFF(`data_expira`, NOW()) < 0 THEN 'Expirado' 
                        ELSE 
                            'Vigente'
                    END) AS `Data`
                FROM 
                    `plano_usuario` 
                WHERE 
                    `user_token` = '%s' 
                AND 
                    `status` = 'A' 
                ORDER BY 
                    `data_cad` 
                        DESC 
                LIMIT 
                    1
                ;";
```